# Building a linkedlist by input

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to get a LinkedList by user input and everything works well, but I don't understand why. In the while loop, I'm constantly setting the 'last' to be the most recent input of num. But I never update 'n1' outside of the loop, so how does it still work? When does n1 get updated and num goes in?

```
 public static Node<int> BuildList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter num: -999 to finish");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Node<int> n1 = new Node<int>(num);
        if (num != -999)
        {
            Node<int> last = n1;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter num: -999 to finish");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("If again");
            
            while (num != -999)
            {
                last.SetNext(new Node<int>(num));
                last = last.GetNext();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter num: -999 to finish");
                num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                
            }
        }
        return n1;         
    }
```

Comment: When you call the `Node` constructor, you pass `num` as argument. The constructor will assign that number to the relevant property of that object. That constructor will also set the `next` property of that node to `null`. Nothing else needs to be updated in that node.

Comment: If `Node<T>` is a reference type (ie class), then it gets update at this line `Node<int> last = n1;`

Answer (score 0):

`Node<T>` is a reference type in C#. When you initialize `Node<int> last = n1;`, you're creating a new reference that points to the same Node object in memory as `n1`.

The first time `SetNext()` is called on `last`, it's being called on the same object as `n1`.

Answer (score 0):

**Why & when does n1 get updated?**

```
Node<int> last = n1;
```

Here you are *assigning `n1` linked list node to a `last` variable*. `n1` and `last` both are of type `Node<int>`. `Node<T>` is a reference type.

When you assign one reference type to another then, this is nothing but two variables are pointing to the same memory location. in your case, it is `Node<int>` location.

In simple words, `n1` and `last` variables pointing to the same linked list node.

[image]

```
last.SetNext(new Node<int>(num)); //Here n1 gets updated.
```

this line adds the next node to the `last` node, ultimately you are adding to the linked list `n1`.

This is the reason, your `n1` linked list is updating its value.

Comment: oh, thanks, I didn't think about it like that

Answer (score 0):

> I never update `n1` outside of the loop,

Actually, it is updated before the loop when it is constructed. Both its value and `next` property are initialised (updated) during the execution of `n1 = new Node<int>(num);`. `last` is made a synonum for it, and in the first call to `SetNext` its `next` property is updated.

The `while` loop creates new nodes, and each time the previously created one gets its `next` property updated with the call to `SetNext`. Each call to `SetNext` makes the list one node longer as the "old" tail makes a link to the "new" tail node.

> When does n1 get updated and num goes in?

`num` gets in the node during its construction. The node gets extended by a next node when that next node is created and `SetNext` is called to make the link with it.

#### Visualisation

It may help to see step by step what happens with an example input of:

```
10
20
30
-999
```

Before the loop starts the first node is created with the value 10, and we enter the `if` block, where `Node<int> last = n1;` is executed. This gets us in this situation;

```
  n1
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ value: 10  │
│ next: null │
└────────────┘
  ↑
 last
```

Then the value 20 is read from input and the loop goes through its first iteration. The following code is executed:

```
last.SetNext(new Node<int>(num));
```

First `new Node<int>(num)` is executed which creates a new node, and this node reference is assigned to the `next` property of `last`. This is the result:

```
  n1
  ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 10  │   │ value: 20  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
  ↑
 last
```

Then `last = last.GetNext();` is executed, which assigns a different node reference to `last`: it's the one that is referenced by `last.next`. So:

```
  n1
  ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 10  │   │ value: 20  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
                   ↑
                  last
```

The next number is read, 30, and a new loop iteration occurs. Again, a new node is created, and its reference is assigned to `last.next` with the `SetNext` call:

```
  n1
  ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 10  │   │ value: 20  │   │ value: 30  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                   ↑
                  last
```

`last` gets assigned the successor node:

```
  n1
  ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 10  │   │ value: 20  │   │ value: 30  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                                    ↑
                                   last
```

And finally, -999 is read as value and this makes the loop end. You can see that `n1` references the head of the list with three nodes, which gets returned to the caller.